# Calculate a date with PHP

Tags: php, date

I am using an html form to get a user inputted date. The structure of the date inputted is: MM/DD/YYYY. I then need to increment the total days by 196 in PHP. Right now, the data is being posted to a php file called Calculate.php. I was looking into altering the data using date (m d Y); in php, but my friend said that probably wont work. Any ideas? Thank you for your time and have a great day! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check out [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). This will convert your MM/DD/YYYY format in to a numeric value you can then work with.
2. Use `strtotime` again to manipulate the date to add the days to it.
3. Use [`strftime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) to re-format it for display.

e.g.

```
$d = '08/11/2011';

$dAsPOSIX = strtotime($d);
$dPlus196Days = strtotime('+196 day', $dAsPOSIX);

echo strftime('%m/%d/%Y',$dPlus196Days);
```

[DEMO](http://www.ideone.com/zSkGE)

Comment: Rather than be obtuse, call it what it is, a UNIX timestamp, not "a [magical?] numeric value" or "DateStamp". :)

Comment: @Dan: How about I call it a POSIX time? ;p

Comment: That would be preferable to making up your own name, at least he can look that up.

Comment: So now I'm curious, who down-voted and why? What about the above is invalid or unacceptable? (Besides my overly-broad naming convention).

Comment: Downvoted for purposely using the obscure term rather than the common one used in the PHP manual and most references. This makes the page less useful to both the asker and to future people with the same question (who will have a harder time finding it in searches).

Comment: @Dan: So if I used [`$dAsTimestamp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#example-658) it would have been more appropriate? I also linked directly to docs; there's no illusion as to what those function names perform and/or return. I also could have just as easily used `$foo` and `$bar`.

Comment: When called out on being purposely hard to understand, you chose to continue to be hard to understand just to spite the comment, *not* because POSIX is what you wanted to call the variable. I feel this choice, to provide worse answers to make points to commentors, should be reflected in your reputation, since you're working against the purpose of the site. I'm sure you'll survive it.

Comment: Thanks Brad for the tip. I would up vote you and Xeon but I can't do that yet :'(

Answer (score 2):

Using `strtotime` magic:

```
strtotime('08/11/2011 +196 days');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = $_POST['date'];

echo date('m d Y', strtotime('+196 days', strtotime($input));
```